# do we need to send mobile_advertiser_id in HASH format while adding users to Facebook custom audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

The table from the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#create) seems to indicate that the hash is needed only for email and phone.

### Key : Description

id : Upload people based on their Facebook ID

email_hash : Upload people based on the hash of their email address

phone_hash : Upload people based on the hash of their phone number

custom_audience_third_party_id : Upload people based on the app user ID

mobile_advertiser_id : Upload people based on the app user ID, Apple's Advertising Identifier (IDFA), or Android's advertising ID.

Is my understanding correct?

Also, do the mobile ids include the hyphens (-) and are there capitalization guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to hash in the case of email and phone, in all other cases you do not need to provide an hash.

For mobile IDs, you should include the exact string that you retrieved from the device.

Comment: The eco-system is very fragmented with some partners working in lower case only, some without hyphens. We tried uploading a list of IDFAs in lower case which seems to work fine with the custom audience API call. Is it ok to do so?

Comment: as far as I know, yes.